# Batch file loop issue - ends batch file

Tags: loops, batch-file, psexec

I have problem with my batch file.

```
    @echo off

:START
echo Are you ready?

SET logpath=xxx

:COPY
pause
xxx

:FIRST
for /f %%g IN (hostnames.txt) do (
::xcopy "xxx*.*" \\%%g\c$\temp\ /f /s /y /i
echo PC %%g >> %logpath%\xxx
echo %%g > appname.txt

psexec -h \\%%g cmd /c msiexec /i xxx
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' (
      echo xxx Success! >> %logpath%\xxx.txt
    ) else (
      echo xxx Error is %ERRORLEVEL%. >> %logpath%\xxx.txt
    )
psexec -h \\%%g cmd /c msiexec /i xxx
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' (
      echo xxx Success! >> %logpath%\xxx.txt
    ) else (
      echo xxx Error is %ERRORLEVEL%. >> %logpath%\xxx.txt
    )


:SECOND
psexec -h \\%%g cmd /c  MsiExec.exe /I{xxx} /passive /norestart 
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' (
      echo test {...-xxx} uninstalled! >> %logpath%\xxx.txt
      goto THIRD
    )

psexec -h \\%%g cmd /c  msiexec /x "{xxx}" /passive /norestart 
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' (
      echo Pierwszy {...-xxx} uninstalled! >> %logpath%\xxx.txt
      goto THIRD
    )

    ::Like 15 times uninstalling different apps

:THIRD

for /f %%g in (appname.txt) do taskkill -s %%g -im xxx.exe -f
for /f %%g in (appname.txt) do psexec -h \\%%g cmd /c  msiexec /i xxx /passive /norestart
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' (
      echo xxx Success! >> %logpath%\xxx.txt
    ) else (
      echo xxx. Error is %ERRORLEVEL%. >> %logpath%\xxx.txt
    )
for /f %%g in (appname.txt) do psexec -h \\%%g cmd /c regedit /s xxx.reg

for /f %%g in (appname.txt) do psexec -h \\%%g cmd /c del c:\temp\xxx\*.* /f /s /q

echo. >> %logpath%\xxx.txt
echo. >> %logpath%\xxx.txt

)
```

At first, like You can see in the THIRD section I need to use `for /f %%g in (appname.txt) do psexec -h` instead of `psexec -h`, because psexec fails and it's "losing" hostname and this is the only workaround which I have found by myself.

Second thing (**most important**) is that when batch runs to the end (to the last ")") it stops. Like the first loop `for` was ended and it doesn't get new hostname from file hostnames.txt

I would be gratefull for any ideas how to make it work

Comment: it is called `enabledelayedexpansion` try from `cmd` to run `setlocal /?`

Comment: First thing to note is that you have unbalanced parentheses, _there seems no reason for the last line/character at all!_ Next thing to note is a distinct lack of doublequotes throughout the script, there are only two sets and one of those is commented out. You appear to be `echo`ing unnecessary space characters to your log file too.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply. I have added 'setlocal enabledelayedexpansion' at the start, and changed 'for /f %%g in (appname.txt) do psexec -h' to 'psexec -h' but there is still the same issue.

Comment: Don't use double colons for comments inside parenthesised code blocks.